# I want to add an action to a catogary bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a page with these categories: All, Events, Activities, Restaurants, Malls.
And it should be content under each of them, How can I add an action to them and choose which content goes under which?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

var category = [
  'All',
  'Events',
  'Activities',
  'Restaurants',
  'Malls',
];

class PostScreen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
              expandedHeight: 300,
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                title: Text('Jubail'),
                background: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/image1.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
//here is the category bar,,,,,,,,,,
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: SizedBox(height: 15),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: SizedBox(height: 6),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 126, 84, 199),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 247, 246, 248),
                                blurRadius: 4,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            category[i],
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ), ), ),],),), ),),

//here is the content (this part gets repeated to add more content),,,,,,,,,,
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 200,
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        Positioned(
                          top: 10,
                          right: 10,
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {},
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.black26,
                                    blurRadius: 6,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 53, 31, 142),
                                size: 20,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        ), ),),),],
```

I used the "for" loop to add the categories.

note: I do not have more details but I am writing this because the website asks me to add more details.

Comment: Do you want to show different content depending by the category bar?

Comment: yes, but all the content can be seen togather in "All" category.

Comment: But the content is a list of events, activities, etc? Or it gonna be a big button or just a big Card?

Comment: I did a research it seems I need to rewrite every thing in order to make it work, so when i finish i will post it.

Comment: thank you, and i am sorry for taking your time.

Comment: Ok, don't worry !